# How to make a column autowrap when using data grid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have some long string in the column. How to make a column auto-wrapping?

Answer (score 4):

For a DataGridTextColumn you can use this

```
<DataGridTextColumn ...>
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: @user496949: Was something like this what you had in mind or what's your usage scenario?

Comment: Do I need to style both TextBox and TextBlock?

Comment: @user496949: It depends. If you have editing enabled in the DataGridTextColumn then I'd recommend it. Otherwise, when you enter edit mode, it will become one long line. If it is readonly, then there's no need to do it

Comment: @user496949: No, that should do it. Do you mean that it doesn't wrap to begin with? Did you try changing the width of the column in runtime? Try setting Width="100" or something